# Get first/second/third element from sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql query like

```
SELECT id FROM chart WHERE name='qwertz' AND run_id=3
```

I know that this query will return 3 datasets. For another complex query I need the first/second/third id that returned my query above like

```
SELECT value FROM data WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM chart WHERE name='qwertz' AND run_id=3).getFirst

 SELECT value FROM data WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM chart WHERE name='qwertz' AND run_id=3).getSecond

 SELECT value FROM data WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM chart WHERE name='qwertz' AND run_id=3).getThird
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Whats the structure of the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OFFSET` with `LIMIT` :

```
SELECT * FROM chart
WHERE name = 'qwertz' and run_id = 3
LIMIT 1,0 -- First record

SELECT * FROM chart
WHERE name = 'qwertz' and run_id = 3
LIMIT 1,1 -- Second record

SELECT * FROM chart
WHERE name = 'qwertz' and run_id = 3
LIMIT 1,2 -- Third record
```

Although with out a specific `ORDER BY` clause, this will be random records!

Can also be written as one query to get all of them together :

```
SELECT * FROM chart
WHERE name = 'qwertz' and run_id = 3
LIMIT 3 -- First 3
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks like the thing I was looking for.

Comment: Without an `order by`, the results are indeterminate and the three queries *could* return the same row.  (Although in practice in MySQL they do not.)

Comment: MySQL won't? I actually meant by "random records" that it can return the same record twice, MySQL avoids it?

Comment: @sagi thank you for your answer it helped me also. However for me was the other way round `LIMIT 0,1` `LIMIT 1,1` `LIMIT 2,1`